Does any complex analytic space has the differential structure?
As well-known a complex manifold always has the  differential manifold  structure. In fact, in the book "Complex Geometry An Introduction" of Huybrechts, he defines a complex manifold as follows:
Definition 2.1.2 A complex manifold $X$ of dimension $n$ is a (real) differentiable manifold of dimension $2 n$ endowed with an equivalence class of holomorphic atlases.
That is to say, after forgetting  some structures on a complex manifold structure, we can get a  differentiable manifold structure
For a complex analytic space, we adopt the definition of "Coherent analytic sheaves" of Grauert and Remmert, as follows:    Let $\left(X, \mathcal{O}_X\right)$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-ringed space such that $X$ is a Hausdorff space: we call $\left(X, \mathcal{O}_X\right)$ a complex space if every point of $X$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that the open $\mathbb{C}$-ringed subspace $\left(U, \mathcal{O}_U\right)$ of $\left(X, \mathcal{O}_X\right)$ is isomorphic to a complex model space. In other words a complex space is a ringed Hausdorff Space which can be locally realized (as a $\mathbb{C}$-ringed space) by the zero set of finitely many holomorphic functions in some domain of a complex number space.
Question: after forgetting  some structures on a complex analytic space structure,  can we always get a  differentiable manifold structure?
Clues: Note that if so, then any complex analytic space must be a differentiable manifold.   This seems to be amazing for me. For example, given a complex manifold $X$, for a holomorphic function
$f:=R_f+i I_f$, its' zero set may not be a complex submanifold, at this time, the Jacobian of the defining equations {$R_f$, $I_f$} of the zero set in the real  differentiable manifold $X$ does not have the maximal rank, and thus the zero set $Z(R_f)\cap Z({I_f})$ may not be a real differentiable submanifold  of the differentiable manifold $X$.  However, in the paper "Closedness of the Douady Spaces of Compact Kahler Spaces By Akira FUJIKi":https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyotoms1969/14/1/14_1_1/_pdf
in page 7, Remark 1.1- 1), the author said that "Using partition of unity we can always construct a Hermitian form on every complex space"  In this place, I think The author may consider the complex space as a differentiable manifold.
Any comments and clues will be appreciated.


Question: after forgetting some structures on a complex analytic space structure, can we always get a differentiable manifold structure?

No. The complex analytic space
$$X = \{\, (x,y) : xy=0 \,\} \subset \mathbb C^2$$
is the union of the two complex lines $\{x=0\}$ and $\{y=0\}$. This is not a differentiable manifold at $0$.

In this place, I think The author may consider the complex space as a differentiable manifold.

What makes you think that? Every paracompact Hausdorff space admits partitions of unity[1].

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space#Partitions_of_unity

Great!  Thank you.  I am now partially  convinced by your answer.  But one thing confusing me is that the Hermitian form defined in Fujiki's paper is assumed to be $C^{\infty}$ (this notion in complex space is defined in page 3 of Fujiki's paper) while the partitions of unity for paracompact Hausdorff space is only ensured to be continuous.

@LelongWang Good point. I'm not immediately sure how to resolve this, maybe one can take partitions of unity which are compatible with the local models $X \supset U \hookrightarrow \mathbb C^n$, i.e. extend to an open neighbourhood of $U$ in $\mathbb C^n$?
